# When i open url of my app it says "Aplication Error". I think I am missing something in the code

Tags: node.js, chatbot

I think the problem is in require function but i couldn't work around this problem.

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')

const app = express ()

app.set('port', [process.env.PORT || 5000])

//allows us to process data
app.use(urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(json())

//  Routes

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.send("Hi How Are You ??")
})

//facebook

app.get('/webhook/',function(req, res){
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === "1234@5678JaneDoe"){
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
    }
    res.send("Wrong Token")
})

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log("Running: port")
})
```

Log

2019-04-24T02:19:39.169277+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-24T02:19:39.169745+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-24T02:19:39.170945+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! chatbot@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-04-24T02:19:39.171123+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-24T02:19:39.171405+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-24T02:19:39.171588+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chatbot@1.0.0 start script.

i tried using the ES6 module for this as

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import request from 'request';
```

but this did not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following

```js
app.set('port', [process.env.PORT || 5000])

//allows us to process data
app.use(urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(json())
```

with

```js
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000) // not an array

//allows us to process data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})) // bodyPraser missing
app.use(bodyParser.json())// bodyPraser missing
```